# Enter data to a MySql database with PHP

Tags: php, updating

I have a MySql database which has users and each user gets a grade see below:

```
ID   NAME   GRADE
1    Sean    10
2    Sarah   15
3    Seo     12
4    Ste     32
```

Basically, I want to be able to dynamically print out whats stored in the database and add a text input box which enables me to enter in grades which are stored for each individual person. I then want this grade to be stored in the database for the user. Is this possible? 
I have code which prints out the users but doesn't include a text box

```
<table style="width:50%" style = "background-color: transparent;">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>GRADE</th> 

  </tr>


<?php

     $sql = "SELECT id, name, grade FROM students";
    $result = $conn -> query ($sql);

    if($result -> num_rows >0){
        //output data of each row

        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row["id"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row["name"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row["grade"] ?> </td>

            </tr>

?>



</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to collect input from a user and save it to a database.  Have you tried anything?  It sounds like you should be starting with some introductory PHP/MySQL tutorials.

Comment: There's a lot to this question; `<form>` and its `<input/>` fields (one input for each `$row`'s `grade` value, a method to `POST` this (whether AJAX or a straight submitted request), PHP logic to handle the submitted info and save that to the database, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Research a bit on HTML forms here
[HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

You can either use post or get methods for the form to send the values to PHP.

After you have set up your form you can simply use the variables $_GET[formvariable] if you are using get or
$_POST[formvariable] if you are using post.

You can then use mysql to update values in the database when the form is submitted.